# Facebook Login for Firefox OS Apps

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk, firefox-os

We are porting an App to Firefox OS but we want to implement the Facebook Login.

We want to make it work only with a client-side. 
We get

> 1. API Error Code: 191
> 2. API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
> 3. Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application >configuration.

We are not allowed to add the http: //localhost/ to Valid OAuth redirect URIs Under the Advanced Settings of the Application.

Is there anyway to fix this. Using redirect_uri or make an iframe that loads the Dialog via the website?

Any idea?

---

In addition to my research i got this from Mozilla Developers

> redirects

(Firefox OS only, privileged and certified apps only) A privileged or certified app might need to do external authentication. For example, the app could do Facebook OAuth authentication so it can get a person's contacts. When the authentication server is finished, it will usually redirect the app back to a URL that you control.

But a privileged or certified app does not have a valid Web URL that can be redirected to, because the app is not hosted anywhere (it is a packaged app with no public origin). So you use the redirects field to redirect a Web URL to an internal app URL.

Example:

```
"redirects": [
{"from": "http://mydomain.com/oauth2/flow.html",
"to": "/redirects/redirect.html"},
{"from": "http://mydomain.com/oauth2/dialogs_end.html",
"to": "/redirects/dialogs_end.html"}
],
```

For any further development i will update the question!

Comment: Can you edit the OS hosts file?

Comment: I researched on that. Editing the hosts files converting it to a domain. That may server my device. What about the other clients hosts files. The ones who download the app.

I got the domain and the facebook login on the website set up. i just want to find a way/solution to make it work on devices like Firefox Os

Comment: Won't other clients use a real/production url? Anyway, i would seperate the environments and build one facebook app for each.

Comment: Firefox OS packaged Apps, unlike the hosted apps, are html5 javascript and css Apps located inside the OS. If the app would be running online, which is not, it would be ok. But they are running in the client. Not on the server. Just to clarify

Comment: After this clarification I must say the I am not familiar with this OS. But, Maybe a solution can be to implement a real facebook login flow from an online site and then pass the access_token to your app from the online site, and use this token in your js sdk api requests. I implemented a similar proccess for chrome extension. Also i found this post http://thenittygritty.co/ffos-apps from googling, probably others fetched those issues as well, did you researched on google?

Comment: And other posts on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirefox-os%5Dfacebook

Comment: Thanks for the help im trying to figure this Out. Maybe the Github oAuth is different from facebook implementation!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48097/discussion-between-arty-and-alen-saqe)